# Attaching files does not work from the "Gallery" application in Android 13

Tags: android, ionic-framework, file-upload, permissions

I am having problems when using the "Attach files" from my application.
From an <input type="file"...> I get this element to return the files that I choose from the different folders, but it does not return anything when I attach files from the "Gallery" application. I don't know if it is necessary in Android to put some permission.

My device is a Xiaomi 11S. Android 13.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPLZQ.png

I have tried different solutions but I have not been able to get it to work. When I use the "Gallery" app, the response from the <input type="file"...> returns empty, using my Android 13 device. Is this happening to anyone else?